# How to improve mulesoft stored procedure insert execution much faster?

Tags: stored-procedures, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

I have created a stored procedure to insert 90,000 records and called it in mule anypointstudio. But it is taking more than 8 hours to execute those records where the same code is executed in perl and was inserted in 15 mins.

Iam using batch to handle stored procedure failure records. I tried changing max threads allowed and not finding any improvements.

Can you help where I am doing wrong in implementation?

Here is the mule code i used:

```
<batch:job name="Import_users_data" max-failed-records="-1">
    <batch:threading-profile maxThreadsActive="1000" poolExhaustedAction="RUN"/>
    <batch:input>
        <db:stored-procedure config-ref="MyLearn_SQLSERVER_DB_Configuration"  doc:name="Database">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[{call spFetch_users_data}]]></db:parameterized-query>

        </db:stored-procedure>
        <set-payload value="#[payload.get('resultSet1')]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    </batch:input>
    <batch:process-records>
        <batch:step name="users_batch_step">
            <db:stored-procedure config-ref="SQLSERVER_DB_Configuration" doc:name="Database" streaming="true">
                <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[{call spIns_data_in_users_table(:in_users_id, :in_first_name, :in_last_name)}]]></db:parameterized-query>

                <db:in-param name="in_users_id" type="INTEGER" value="#[payload.USERS_ID]"/>
                <db:in-param name="in_first_name" type="VARCHAR" value="#[payload.FIRST_NAME]"/>
                <db:in-param name="in_last_name" type="VARCHAR" value="#[payload.LAST_NAME]"/>


            </db:stored-procedure>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:process-records>
    <batch:on-complete>
        <logger message="Successfully imported users data.......#['Successfull Records: '+payload.successfulRecords+'Failed Records: '+payload.failedRecords]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <flow-ref name="Export_data" doc:name="Export_data"/>
    </batch:on-complete>
</batch:job>
```

Answer (score 0):

@shabrinath, try increasing the `Batch Block Size` value to higher than the default value of 100 for the `Batch Scope`.

Comment: i`m using anypoint studio 5.4.0 where the batch block size is not available. Cant update since I dont have permissions. Is there any alternate way for Anypointstudio 5.4.0?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is available from Mule 3.8 and Anypoint Studio 6 onwards. You can upgrade Anypoint Studio to 6 to avail this option.